# "Key not valid for use in specified state" CLI program

Tags: windows

I am using qbittorrent-cli program to, obviously, script things in qBittorrent.  Was working great then out of nowhere I started getting this error when trying to use it. "Key not valid for use in specified state". The person who wrote the CLI program says it's not on his program and looking up the error I agree. Something to do with certifications on my system.

I have deleted the folder "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto" per several suggestions. I have uninstalled the CLI program and reinstalled it. Tried running SFC. Still get the error.

Anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: Saw the same error message once, here is a write-up: https://rathertech.blogspot.com/2014/06/cryptoapi-issue-ive-found.html Replace "c:\Documents and Settings" with "c:\Users"; it was a WinXP-era post. CREDHIST might be elsewhere these days.

Comment: I have full control over this file and it is not read only

Comment: Oh well, worth a try. If you are up to the task, debug the CLI app, place a breakpoint on SetLastError, see what happens.

Comment: Yeah I apricate the suggestion.  Confused at this point.  I am not a programmer (I do IT support so basic scripting only), would not know where to start with that

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  It WAS the CLI program but it was just the credentials inside the program.  Once I cleared them and reentered them it works